# NGINX Server Is Not Starting [ Closed ]

Tags: nginx

My NGINX server have stopped and it is generating error.

I am using Ubantu 16.04 and my app deploye at Digital Ocean Server.

When I run the following colde `sudo systemctl start nginx` It is giving following output:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `$ nginx -t` is:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/root/bitradiology.chained.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/root/bitradiology.chained.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I checked the status with `$ sudo systemctl status nginx`

output is:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-08-21 11:01:51 UTC; 1min 50s ago
  Process: 2085 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 2420 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2462 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 nginx[2420]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/root/bitradiology.chained.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such 
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 nginx[2420]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 21 11:01:51 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

How to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

I found this `bitradiology.chained.crt` file into the `cd /usr` directory.

Then go to the following directory `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and open the default file

```
sudo nano default
```

I edited this file and replaced `/root/` by `/usr/`

`/root/bitradiology.chained.crt` by  `/usr/bitradiology.chained.crt`

I run the nginx config test first:

```
nginx -t
```

after the test ran successful, I can restart the service

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

NGINX has been started and my app is running right now.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your **ssl_certificate** instructions in your config files.
Nginx is clearly saying it can't find one of the files specified:

> fopen:No such file or
>   directory:fopen('/root/bitradiology.chained.crt','r')